# How to run Chisq test for multiple rows FASTER in R?

Tags: r, performance, loops, dplyr, chi-squared

I have managed to do chisq-test using loop in R but it is very slow for a large data and I wonder if you could help me out doing it faster with something like dplyr? I've tried with dplyr but I ended up getting an error all the time which I am not sure about the reason.

Here is a short example of my data:

```
    df
           1        2        3        4        5
row_1  2260.810 2136.360 3213.750 3574.750 2383.520
row_2   328.050  496.608  184.862  383.408  151.450
row_3   974.544  812.508 1422.010 1307.510 1442.970
row_4  2526.900  826.197 1486.000 2846.630 1486.000
row_5  2300.130 2499.390 1698.760 1690.640 2338.640
row_6   280.980  752.516  277.292  146.398  317.990
row_7   874.159  794.792 1033.330 2383.420  748.868
row_8   437.560  379.278  263.665  674.671  557.739
row_9  1357.350 1641.520 1397.130 1443.840 1092.010
row_10 1749.280 1752.250 3377.870 1534.470 2026.970


cs 
 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 3
```

What I want to do is to run chisq-test between each row of the df and cs. Then giving me the statistics and p.values as well as row names.

here is my code for the loop:

```
value = matrix(nrow=ncol(df),ncol=3)


for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  tst <- chisq.test(df[i,], cs)
  value[i,1] <- tst$p.value
  value[i,2] <- tst$statistic
  value[i,3] <- rownames(df)[i]}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't the index be `i in 1:nrow(df)`? Also, I see nothing being done with the `tbl` object, and further you could assign all the rownames at once (outside the loop)  with `value[[3]] <- rownames(df)`. The `dplyr` functions don't generally make things faster. It's goal is to make things more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do want to do this column by column. Knowing the structure of `Biobase::exprs(PANCAN_w))` would have helped greatly. Even better would have been to use an example from the Biobase package instead of a dataset that cannot be found.

This is an implementation of the code I might have used. Note: you do NOT want to use a matrix to store results if you are expecting a mixture of numeric and character values. You would be coercing all the numerics to character:

```
value = data.frame(p_val =NA,  stat =NA, exprs = rownames(df) )

for (i in 1:col(df)) {
  # tbl <- table((df[i,]), cs) ### No use seen for this
  # I changed the indexing in the next line to compare columsn to the standard `cs`.

  tst <- chisq.test(df[ ,i], cs)  #chisq.test not vectorized, need some sort of loop

  value[i, 1:2] <- tst[ c('p.value', 'statistic')]  # one assignment per row
     }
```

Obviously, you would need to change every instance of `df` (not a great name since there is also a `df` function) to `Biobase::exprs(PANCAN_w)`